# Backup Exec tape rotation guidelines

Tags: backupexec

We use Backup Exec to take care of our backups for our data server, exchange server, and one more set of systems. Each of these 3 is being done on a separate "set" of tapes.
Our goal is to be able to roll back a full 2 weeks, with 1 full backup each weekend and differential/incremental backups in between (the difference between the two in our case isn't very big, because the employees mostly use a very similar set of files throughout the week).

While playing around with the settings on how to achieve this, we set the time for BE to keep the full backup to 14 days, but because we have too much data this would require manual intervention each time to erase a certain tape and use that.

What I would like to know is what kind of guidelines, tricks, tips and general "stuff to think about" you keep in mind when designing your backup schedule. The type of backups (full/diff/incr) isn't of that much importance in our case as it's more or less set in stone.

Made this community wiki as it's not a very specific question.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't bother doing three different sets of backups to three different media pools - make one big pool and backup to that.

Are you using a tape changer?

Comment: if by tapechanger you mean have a "box" with some 24ish tapes in it with a robot selecting the ones that needs to be written or read, then yes. I'm not expert on the subject, my colleague does most of the work but I had something in mind he has apparently never heard of so I wanted to check some other alternatives here

Comment: Yes, that's a "changer", "autochanger",  "library", "or "robot." How many drives do you have in it? Is it just one?

What did you have in mind, that your colleague was unfamiliar with?